# iOS: How do I find out what "fallback font" is used when I try to display Japanese characters with my western font?

Tags: ios, fonts, internationalization

I'm displaying strings with a combination of Japanese and western characters. I know what font I'm using for the western characters...but how do I find out what font is used for the Japanese characters?

(And can I change it?)

Answer (score 2):

The default Japanese system font in iOS is Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN W3. It's also the default fallback for displaying Japanese text when using a Latin font. In my own experience, it doesn't matter whether a Latin serif or sans serif font is in use—Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN W3 is still used for the Japanese text.

(The more interesting question is how you'd go about changing it.)